# Not sure how to route to my React views in Laravel

Tags: reactjs, laravel, routes

I'm trying to route to my react *viewName.js* files through Laravel but I'm not quite sure how to get this done. I'll be routing through a sidebar to change from one view to another, but I'm not sure how to set up the routing path in React.

My app.js

```
import React, { Component }from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

// Layouts
import Header from '../components/layouts/Header';
import Sidebar from '../components/layouts/Sidebar';

// Views
import Repos from '../components/views/Repos';
import Hooks from '../components/views/Hooks';
import Issues from '../components/views/Issues';
import Members from '../components/views/Member';

class Index extends Component {
    render() {
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <Header />
            <Sidebar /> 
            <Repos />
            <Hooks />
            <Issues />
            <Member />
        </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Index;

if (document.getElementById('index')) {
    ReactDOM.render(<Index />, document.getElementById('index'));
}
```

My web.php

```
Route::view('/{path?}', 'welcome');
```

The sidebar

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import List from '@material-ui/core/List'
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem'
import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class Sidebar extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <List disablePadding dense style={styleSidebar}>
        <ListItem button>
          <ListItemText style={textStyle}>Repos</ListItemText>
        </ListItem>
        <ListItem button>
          <ListItemText style={textStyle}>Events</ListItemText>
        </ListItem>
        <ListItem button>
          <ListItemText style={textStyle}>Hooks</ListItemText>
        </ListItem>
        <ListItem button>
          <ListItemText style={textStyle}>Issues</ListItemText>
        </ListItem>
        <ListItem button>
          <ListItemText style={textStyle}>Members</ListItemText>
        </ListItem>
      </List>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Add more details for your question

Comment: @krimo I've added a bit more detail

Comment: the sidbar is in react js ?

Comment: @krimo Yes. I went ahead and added the sidebar code

Answer (score 0):

try this Principle

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
<Router> 
   <Link to="/Repos" >Repos</Link>
   <Link to="/Events" >Events</Link>
    {<Route  exact path="/Repos" component={Repos} />}
    {<Route  exact path="/Events" component={Events} />}
</Router>
```

Comment: Foolish question, I assume you mean to try this in my app.js?

Comment: what you mean @DevJ

Comment: put it in Sidebar component then change the style  as you want @DevJ

Comment: It's unfortunately throwing an error "app.js:83461 Uncaught ReferenceError: Events is not defined" (for example)

Comment: in the component put your component of each page  @DevJ

Answer (score 0):

use router component like the guy above me wrote and the index render should look like that
[image]

you can see my index file here
https://github.com/lidorMarko/SkiStore/blob/main/src/index.js